# Document library - Cannot overwrite documents but can save a copy

Tags: document-library

I want to create a document library that will have about 200 templates for users to use.

I want to set this so when a user clicks on a excel template then cannot overwrite the original but can save a copy

I am using Office 365 SharePoint 2013

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set individual permissions for each template file, so regular users have read permissions for these files, but contribute permissions to the library.